# PHP for each loop in $_POST

Tags: php, json, foreach

I was creating a shareable form and use JSON for the structure. Im just stuck when anyone is about to submit the data on the form.

```
{
"table-name": "Locations-Grid view(1)",
"created-on": "May 13, 2021",
"token": "nKdcXx2d0bbLifg",
"columns": "Locations,Lat,Lng",
"data": [
    {
        "Locations": "Mumbai 1",
        "Lat": "19.088008",
        "Lng": "72.882959"
    },
    {
        "Locations": "Mumbai 2",
        "Lat": "19.088008",
        "Lng": "72.882959"
    },
    {
        "Locations": "Mumbai 3",
        "Lat": "19.088008",
        "Lng": "72.882959"
    },
    {
        "Locations": "Mumbai 4",
        "Lat": "19.088008",
        "Lng": "72.882959"
    },
    {
        "Locations": "Mumbai 5",
        "Lat": "19.088008",
        "Lng": "72.882959"
    },
    {
        "Locations": "Mumbai 6",
        "Lat": "19.088008",
        "Lng": "72.882959"
    },
    {
        "Lng": "45254"
    },
    {
        "Lng": "455"
    }
]
```

}

As you can see the **last 2 items** are not storing the "Locations" and "Lat", and still got ONLY the "Lng". Here what I do on the my inputs elements using PHP, after inspecting each input name, it was successful print on the html, as you can see i use elements name, exactly same as what columns in my JSON

```
$jsn = file_get_contents('tables/test.json');
$arr = json_decode($jsn, true);
$data = $arr["columns"];
$pars = explode(',',$data);

//create DOM inputs according to each columns in my array

foreach ($pars as $value) {
    $DOM .= '<div class="relative md:w-full lg:w-full mr-30 popup">
                <label for="hero-field" class="leading-7 text-sm text-gray-600"> <span>'.$value.'</span</label>
                <input type="text" name="'.$value.'" class="w-full bg-gray-100 rounded border bg-opacity-50 border-gray-300 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:bg-transparent focus:border-indigo-500 text-base outline-none text-gray-700 py-1 px-3 leading-8 transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out" value="" required>
            </div>';
}
```

This how it looks in my html. And working

```
<form class="w-full" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"style="margin-left:40px;">
    <?php echo $DOM; ?>
    <button type="submit" class="inline-flex text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-lg">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

The problem is **when submitting** using the POST method, it saving on the JSON but only saving the "Lng". Here what i did

```
$data1 = $arr["data"];
$data = $arr["columns"];
$pars = explode(',',$data);
foreach ($pars as $value) {
    $temp = array( $value => $_POST[$value],);
}  

//sending it
array_push($data1,$temp);
$arr["data"] =$data1
if(file_put_contents('tables/test.json',json_encode($arr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))){
    echo 'submitted';
        
}else{
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop is overwriting `$temp` each time round the loop, hence you only get the last occurance from the array

```
foreach ($pars as $value) {
    $temp = array( $value => $_POST[$value],);
}
```

Instead do

```
foreach ($pars as $value) {
    $temp[$value] = $_POST[$value];
}
```